# jQuery toggle on click out

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, events

I have a series of spans (*togglers*) and a series of divs (*toggled*). I created a make_toggle function that receives the toggler and its corresponding toggled as arguments.

Everything seems to work kind of ok up to the point where I try to implement a "toggle on click out". What I've tried is to attach to the html click event a function that checks whether the target of the click is contained within the toggled element. On toggle "back", I would then detach the handler so I am only checking when I need.

```
var check_if_clickingout = function(e) {
  if (!toggled[0].contains(e.target)) {
    toggle();
  }
};
```

See fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/andinse/65o211nc/11/

It doesn't even seem to work anymore but when it used to, it was triggering many more times than necessary (which was the reason for me to come here ask for help).

What am I doing wrong? What is the most effective way to go about this kind of situation where I am giving functionality to a series of independent DOM elements?

Comment: Why not just use `.toggleClass()`?

Answer (score 0):

Just putting this out here that this seems to do the same thing.

```
$("span").click(function() {
  $(this).siblings("div").toggleClass("blue");
});
```

Maybe I am missing something more that I am not seeing in your example.

See more: http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/

Comment: Yes, sorry, I'm actually not trying to toggle a class - this was to simplify the problem. In the context of my project, what happens within "activate" and "deactivate" is different / more developed.
My question is: how do i "deactivate" a div (in the context of this example) by clicking out of it, without interfering with the other four instances of toggler-toggled couples?
Hope that makes sense.

Comment: @user6865443 sorry, no, it does not make sense. Too ambiguous. You could add, `if($(this).hasClass("blus")){ activate(); } else { deactivate(); }`

Comment: What does "this" represent here? Isn't it what is already happening in the below extract?
    `var toggle = function() {
      if (!toggled.is('.blue')) {
        activate();
      } else {
        deactivate();
      }
    };`
Again my problem is the "clicking out" part.

Comment: @user6865443 in my answer, `$(this)` is the element that was clicked. You can add to this callback to execute a specific function depending on  the class that is currently active on the element.